# How to solve excessive CPU load Proteus error?

Tags: simulation, proteus

I'm simulating a virtual Arduino on Proteus. When I test my code, This error appear:

> Simulation is not running in real time due to excessive CPU load

For me, It does not matter to watch the real time output wave form. Can I record it and see it later or something like that to solve this issue? I just need to see the first 5 seconds of the output wave form?

Comment: It looks like a warning, not error.

Comment: The output voltage should alternate between HIGH and LOW each second but it does not. It is always HIGH. Is that because of the warning or my codes are wrong? It worked before when  the code was simpler and when there was no warning.

Comment: It is possible to run proteus at a slowed down speed?, not in real time?, i.e. to use x0.5 or x0.25?

Comment: I know it's old but ajithtomy's solution fixed this issue for me. Reduce the clockspeed in the settings/properties for the simulated Arduino. There might be some performance issues to work out but for simulation purposes, it does the trick for the most part.

Comment: [Proteus CPU over load issue;How to do fast simulation with proteus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/568318/287155)

Answer (score 2):

That's due to 16mhz cpu speed
Search for 1mhz 9600baud rate Arduino Uno board generate hex and load into proteous issue solved

Comment: Please use complete sentences with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the clock frequency of the Arduino Uno board to 1MHz. It may work for equal or less than 5MHz.